# Не работает merge stl

Tags: c++

У меня есть класс `Patient` и два вектора, которые содержат экземпляры этого класса, `patients` и `newPatients`. Я хочу объединить их в один вектор `fullListOfPatients` с помощью функции merge.

`merge(patients.begin(), patients.end(), newPatients.begin(), newPatients.end(), std::back_inserter(fullListOfPatients));`

Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: А что не так? Вектора-то сортированные хоть?

Comment: а надо сортированые?

Comment: отсортировал и всё равно не работает

Comment: Оба отсортировали?

Comment: sort(newPatients.begin(), newPatients.end(), [](Patient pat1, Patient pat2) {return pat1.GetDistrict() > pat2.GetDistrict(); });
 sort(patients.begin(), patients.end(), [](Patient pat1, Patient pat2) {return pat1.GetDistrict() > pat2.GetDistrict(); });
Оба

Comment: Дайте угадаю: ошибка компиляции?

Comment: я не знаю ошибка это компиляции или нет, там 5 ошибок высвечивается. Все из файла xutility

Comment: А так: `merge(patients.begin(), patients.end(), newPatients.begin(), newPatients.end(), std::back_inserter(fullListOfPatients), [](const Patient& p1, const Patient& p2){return p1.GetDistrict() > p2.GetDistrict();});`?

Comment: да, спасибо! Правда без констант, на них ругается

Comment: Нужно, чтобы еще   класс Patient имел операторы `== `  и `!=`